# Wordpress is overriding custom HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Created some custom html, css and JS for a landing page. All of them are external, meaning that I've created for each JS a separate file this is also the case for CSS. I do not want to put them all in one .PHP file because it will be too clouded/messy. Incidentally, this Landin Page is different from the rest of the site in terms of design etc.

Now I'm trying to upload this splashscreen.php into my current theme /wp-content/themes/currenttheme and the folder called "splash screen" (it has the folders assets and images; which include my CSS and JS) in /wp-content/themes/currenttheme

Btw this is how I'm linking to the external CSS and JS. I've also tried adding the whole path, but it didn't work either.

```
  <?php
 /**
 * Template name: landing page
*/

 ?><head>
    <title>landing page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://example.com/splash-screen/assets/css/main.css">
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://example.com/assets/css/ie9.css"><![endif]-->

<noscript><link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://example.com/splash- screen/assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
                <header id="header">

                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h1>Welcome</h1>
                            <p>Welcome to my site <br /> please choose your destination</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#example">example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#example"> example</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#example">example</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>

            <!-- Main -->
                <div id="main">

                    <!-- example-->
                        <article id="example">
                            <h2 class="major">example</h2>
                            <span class="image main"> <a href="http://www.examplecom/"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/splash-screen/images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></span>
                            <p>Aenean ornare velit lacus, ac varius enim ullamcorper eu. Proin aliquam facilisis ante interdum congue. Integer mollis, nisl amet convallis, porttitor magna ullamcorper, amet egestas mauris. Ut magna finibus nisi nec lacinia. Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. By the way, check out my <a href="#work">awesome work</a>.</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dapibus rutrum facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam tristique libero eu nibh porttitor fermentum. Nullam venenatis erat id vehicula viverra. Nunc ultrices eros ut ultricies condimentum. Mauris risus lacus, blandit sit amet venenatis non, bibendum vitae dolor. Nunc lorem mauris, fringilla in aliquam at, euismod in lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In non lorem sit amet elit placerat maximus. Pellentesque aliquam maximus risus, vel sed vehicula.</p>
                        </article>

                    <!-- example-->
                        <article id="example">
                            <h2 class="major">example</h2>
                            <span class="image main"> <a href="http://exampleAB.com/"><img src="splash-screen/images/pic01.jpg" alt="" />    </span>
                            <p>Adipiscing magna sed dolor elit. Praesent eleifend dignissim arcu, at eleifend sapien imperdiet ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent urna nisi, fringila lorem et vehicula lacinia quam. Integer sollicitudin mauris nec lorem luctus ultrices.</p>
                            <p>Nullam et orci eu lorem consequat tincidunt vivamus et sagittis libero. Mauris aliquet magna magna sed nunc rhoncus pharetra. Pellentesque condimentum sem. In efficitur ligula tate urna. Maecenas laoreet massa vel lacinia pellentesque lorem ipsum dolor. Nullam et orci eu lorem consequat tincidunt. Vivamus et sagittis libero. Mauris aliquet magna magna sed nunc rhoncus amet feugiat tempus.</p>
                        </article>

                    <!-- example-->
                        <article id="example">
                            <h2 class="major">example</h2>
                            <span class="image fit"> <a   href="http://example123.com/"><img src="splash-screen/images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></span>
                            <p>Adipiscing magna sed dolor elit. Praesent eleifend dignissim arcu, at eleifend sapien imperdiet ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent urna nisi, fringila lorem et vehicula lacinia quam. Integer sollicitudin mauris nec lorem luctus ultrices.</p>
                            <p>Nullam et orci eu lorem consequat tincidunt vivamus et sagittis libero. Mauris aliquet magna magna sed nunc rhoncus pharetra. Pellentesque condimentum sem. In efficitur ligula tate urna. Maecenas laoreet massa vel lacinia pellentesque lorem ipsum dolor. Nullam et orci eu lorem consequat tincidunt. Vivamus et sagittis libero. Mauris aliquet magna magna sed nunc rhoncus amet feugiat tempus.</p>
                        </article>

            <!-- Footer -->
                <footer id="footer">
                    <p class="copyright">&copy; The Orginal example</p>
                </footer>

        </div>

    <!-- BG -->
        <div id="bg"></div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="splash-screen/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="splash-screen/assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="splash-screen/assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="splash-screen/assets/js/main.js"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

So, when I create a new page I just select the custom template that I've made (landingpage.php). But, when I go look at it the page gets the theme/plugins/JS/analytics from the theme instead of the custom ones that I've made.

So, what is the problem and how can I fix this uploading/not recognizing issue. Btw, my understanding of coding is beginner level.

Comment: Have you tried adding `<base href="http://www.yourwebsite.com/">` and then use  links that are relative the that `href`?

Comment: What does your actual `landingpage.php` look like? Are you using `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`?

Comment: Nope. Not using any of those. There's nothing of wp/wordpress in my codes.

Comment: If this is supposed to be completely independent of your WordPress installation … then why are you cramming it into your theme folder to begin with?

Comment: ^ agreed, and why do your paths not contain /wp-content/themes/currenttheme/ ?

Comment: What is the appropriate location to place them (the .PHP and assets)? Where if I want to create a page with that particular modifications

Comment: /wp-content/themes/currenttheme/  is not working so I've tried the root, current theme, themes and wp-content. Not of those locations seems to be working